# Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets

In my java application i have two textfields which contain listening and sending port number. This application runs well on 1 client and server machine. How can i make it work on multiple clients to 1 server. 
eg on Client Side :
listening port = 2345
sending port = 2346

on Server Side :
listening port = 2346
sending port = 2345

this works for 1 client and server. How can i make it work for multiple clients with the server.

Comment: Why do you specify the sending port number? And why does your Client listen?

Comment: Agreed, sending the port information is not required. What matters is the endpoint on both ends of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would like to accept an incoming request, and handle that request in a separate thread, so that your main thread can continue to listen for new requests. An excellent example (including code) can be found at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html#later.